# How to change screen resolution on Oracle Windows Compute Instance?

Tags: windows, oracle, cloud, screen-resolution, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am a new user using Oracle VPS with Trial Credits, and I was wondering how do I change the screen resolution from 800x600 to 1920x1080? I found the articles below, but am unable to see the solution, and I am unsure if the below articles would be the solution. I don't really know how to navigate the Oracle instance, so I may have to change something there, but again I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2898632_1.html https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Linux%20and%20Virtualization/975855_1.html

I tried running QRes as well as using Set Display Resolution command, but those did nothing.